# Targeting JSF 2.0 components in CSS

Tags: java, css, jsf

I'm developing my first project using JSF 2.0, so forgive me if this is a stupid question.  However, I can't seem to find an answer to this question after Googling it.

Basically, I have a stylesheet which, as an example, adds this style:

```
body {
    padding-top: 60px;
}
```

This works fine if my HTML file uses the `<body>` tag, but doesn't work if I use `<h:body>` (assuming I import the JSF HTML taglib with the shortcut "h").

This is the same for any other components, which is a pain, especially when trying to style form components.

Any help would be very much appreciated.  Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> *but doesn't work if I use `<h:body>` (assuming I import the JSF HTML taglib with the shortcut "h").*

This is **not** true. JSF runs in webserver. JSF generates HTML. Webserver sends this HTML to browser. All the browser get is JSF-generated HTML, not JSF source code itself. CSS runs in browser only. All the CSS will work on is the JSF-generated HTML. Open the JSF page in browser, rightclick and *View Source* to see it yourself. The `<h:body>` has become `<body>`.

If you have a problem with your CSS, it's caused elsewhere. At least, you need to design your CSS based on the JSF-generated HTML output, not on the JSF source code.

Comment: Actually, this **is** true.  I realise the concept behind how JSF renders HTML to the browser, which confuses me even more.  You are right in saying this should not happen, I understand that.  My problem is that it **is** happening.

The problem happens exactly as detailed in my question.  If I change the `<body>` tag to an `<h:body>` tag, the CSS does not render on the element.

Comment: So, the browser has retrieved unparsed JSF source code? The browser has retrieved `<h:body>` instead of `<body>`? Then that means that the `FacesServlet` is not been invoked. Make sure that request URL in browser address bar matches its `<url-pattern>`, or easier, just change its  `<url-pattern>` to `*.xhtml` so that you don't need to fiddle with virtual URLs like `*.jsf`. As said, this is a completely different problem cause :)